# Tuning APC to use less RAM

Tags: php, apc

I have a virtual private server that only allows me to use 128MB of RAM.  I recently installed [APC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php) for PHP and it consumes more than 128MB.  My provider wants me to upgrade my account if I don't get that number down.  Is there a config option that I can use to set a maximum on APC?

Comment: The APC page you link to includes the answer `apc.shm_segments` * `apc.shm_size` as set in your `php.ini`

Comment: Make sure to check how much RAM APC is actually using (it allocates a statically configured block of memory, but may only use a fraction of it -- or it may need even more than has been confiugred) by running the `apc.php` script that comes with APC.  APC performs poorly when it doesn't have enough memory to cache all your code.  If you're seeing any sort of meaningful traffic, you should really consider upgrading.  128 MB is tiny; the number of simultaneous requests you'll be able to handle will be very limited.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the apc.shm_size config option. [APC Configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.shm-size)

Answer (score 2):

[It seems](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php) you need to make changes to [`apc.shm_segments`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.shm-segments) and [apc.shm_size](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.shm-size) to change overall memory given to APC.

Comment: I believe setting `shm_segments` is only advised if you've already maxed out `shm_size`.

Comment: I have shm_size=10 and shm_segments=1.  How do these numbers influence MB of use?  I am using php5-cgi w/ lighttpd.

Comment: from the same page, they say `shm_size` is in MB, and the total usage will be `apc.shm_segments`* `apc.shm_size`, as @Rudi pointed out above.

Comment: His goal is to lower ram usage, not increasing it.

Comment: @bokan: the suggestion is to _change_ the setting, he can either decrease it or increase it.

Comment: Lowering memory without fine tuning which files are cached will just remove the benefits of APC. APC use 32M by default, if it uses 128M there then User1 already know how to change the settings. I thought you read the question too fast and were answering how to increase. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

The goal of APC is to save CPU by spending more ram.
You have to allow enough ram so the pages you want to cache will stay cached for next request. 128M is low, a single Wordpress require 20M

To lower the ram required you can :

- merge installations of your scripts if they support multisites and multidomain (Wordpress, Magento...). If you make 10 websites using only one installation you save 90% of ram.
- filter the files cached : use [apc.filters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.filters) to select only the most accessed PHP files and ignore rarely accessed ones.

Fine tuning APC is about giving him enough RAM so it never have to flush cache.

Frank Farmer advice is good. Use apc.php.

It's funny to see everybody answering how to increase memory where you want to actually lower it. And they get point for that ! :)

Comment: It's actually more funny how you got the idea that "everybody answering how to increase memory" :)
BTW you have good points in your answer, but it needs some cleanup and references.

Comment: My answer don't need references, it's common sense that less files chached uses less memory. I just explained how to do that.

Comment: I meant some links and stuff, to make it more helpful. And yes you are right when it comes to your advices :) upvoted.